# Recommended portable C solution under Windows

Tags: windows, linux, c, portable

I would like to set-up the most appropriate C development environment under Windows, with the scope of having the least painful issues concering code portability to Linux.
In the past I have both used Visual Studio, as well as Visual Code with Mingw32; neither provided full portability and I imagine that is still the case today.
Now, in 2021, I am not aware about the latest versions of Microsoft's IDE, build tools and libraries, as well as possible other third party tools.
Therefore I would kindly ask for your educated and experienced advice.
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295056/c-program-cross-platform-differences-on-windows-and-unix-os ; Good enviornments: CodeBlocks is good but a much better one would be Eclipse. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/kepler/sr2/eclipse-ide-cc-developers

Comment: Did you try National Instruments or Telerik?